# Grails build on build server failing

Tags: grails, teamcity

When running the build of our Grails app locally, it works fine. However, when it runs out on our TeamCity instance, after it does the unit tests and goes into the integration test phase, this happens:

```
[13:15:35][exec] Configuring Spring Security Core ...
[13:15:36][exec] ... finished configuring Spring Security Core
[13:15:36][exec] 
[13:26:43][exec] Error |
[13:26:43][exec] Fatal error running tests: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
[13:26:43][exec] Tests FAILED |
[13:26:43][exec] 
[13:26:45][exec] Error |
[13:26:45][exec] Error executing script TestApp: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
[13:26:45][exec] Result: 1
```

Any clue why this would happen on the build box but not locally? I can't find anything that makes sense to me.

Comment: Make sure you have setup properly the database for test environment, which does not seem to be properly set up

Comment: What commands are you using to build?

Comment: Yes, turned out that it was the database. We'd recently upgraded grails versions and I missed the note about the H2 DB needing a separate dependency now.